# cannot change cmake executable output directory on windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I have a project that builds on both Linux and Windows.
In that, I have in a subfolder `somedir/modules/MyModule` a CMakeLists.txt which should add some test executables. cmake wants to put them in some subdirectory binary folder, but I want to place them in the common binary folder under `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/x64`

So what I'm doing is this (in the CMakeLists.txt in the `somedir/modules/MyModules` directory):

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(MyTest MyTest.cpp)
set_target_properties(MyTest PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/x64")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyTest SomeLibraries...)
ADD_TEST(MyTest ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/x64/MyTest)
```

Under Linux this works nicely, but under Windows I simply cannot get it to build into the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/x64` folder. I've checked via `MESSAGE`, the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/x64` does point to the right folder. I also tried changing the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` (or even the per-target variables, e.g. `CMAKE_MyTest_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, `MyTest_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_Release`, `MyTest_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_Debug`, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328001/671366). Tested both before or after `ADD_EXECUTABLE`, doesn't change anything. The output directory stays fixed on `somedir/modules/x64/`.

I'm out of ideas what I need to do, or even where the output directory it insists on using is coming from. Any ideas? At which point in time is the output directory decided in cmake? How does this relate to subdirectories?  The executables specified in the parent folder CMakeLists.txt files get built in the desired directory, but if that is by mere chance I can't really say.

Comment: Are you sure that you doesn't use `set_target_properties (<target> PROPERTIES PREFIX "../")` or similar somewhere? Default output directory `../x64` looks strange. (It is your output directory `somedir/modules/x64/` relative to `CMakeLists.txt` location `somedir/modules/MyModules`) .

Comment: Isn't it related to the fact that you call ADD_EXECUTABLE and ADD_TEST with the same target name ?

Comment: What if you try something like:  `ADD_TEST(NAME MyTestName COMMAND MyTest)` ?

Comment: @Tsyvarev the only other `set_target_properties` in the whole project is this: `set_target_properties(${ITK} PROPERTIES MAP_INPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBUGINFO RELEASE)` (not sure what it does, that's code I didn't write), and also not setting PREFIX anywhere

Comment: @RenépaulDebroize I thought `add_executable` and `add_test` were both required, and in that way - one to create the executable, and the other to add the produced executable as test - is that wrong? adding `name`/`command` to add_test unfortunately didn't change anything.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your comment. You're right, but i am wondering if cmake is not messed up because you have tow targets with the same name (even if tests target are maybe a special kind of target). How cmake can know to which of those tow targets it has to apply the property.

Comment: @codeling: What `CMake` version you use? And what generator (Visual Studio, ...)? If you use `nmake` generator, try to build with `nmake /S` for verbose output, and check lines related to building `MyTest`. What kind of path to the output file(absolute, relative, contains "..") in that lines?

Comment: using cmake 3.3.1 with generator "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64". have never worked with "NMake Makefiles" generator and it seems kind of picky (only runnable from command line?), will try to get it to run

Comment: @Tsyvarev your "..\x64" prefix brought me finally on the right track! we do have a definition of `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_[DEBUG|RELEASE|...]`, which was set to `../x64` in our root CMakeLists.txt. That seems to override all other settings! Not sure why - shouldn't target-specific properties be able to overwrite this? will have to test some more. in any case, if you post this as answer, I'll accept ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config-specific property `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>` has priority over common one `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. Both types of properties are initialized from corresponded `CMAKE_*` variable(if it is set) when executable target is created.

So, having e.g `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` config-specific variable being set makes this variable to be used for `Debug` configuration even if `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property is explicitely set. The only way to redefine output directory in that case is to set `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` config-specific property.